# Vector space of transformations

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If U and V are finite dinensional vector spaces of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively. W is subspace of $U$
If $Z$ is the collection of all linear transformation from U to V such that they are zero on $W$.then the dimension of Z?
I know that the dimension of the vector space $L(U,V)$ is $mn$.but cant figure out this one??please help

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=\dim W$ and choose a basis $\{w_1,...,w_k\}$ of $W$ and a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ of $V$. Then you can extend $\{w_1,...,w_k\}$ to a basis $\{w_1,...,w_k,u_1,...,u_{m-k}\}$ of $U$, so every $u\in U$ can be uniquely written as $u=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iw_i \, +\sum_{i=1}^{m-k}\beta_iu_i$, where $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$ are scalars.

Now for every $i\in\{1,...,m-k\}$ and $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ define a linear transformation
$L_{ij}:U\rightarrow V$ by $L_{ij}(u)=L_{ij}(\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_iw_i \, +\sum_{i=1}^{m-k}\beta_iu_i)=\beta_iv_j$. Then $L_{ij}(W)=\{0\}$ and you can show that the $L_{ij}$'s form a basis of $Z$, so $\dim Z=(m-k)n$.